# How to load the pollUntil helper in Intern 2 functional tests

Tags: javascript, testing, functional-testing, intern

The intern 2 documentation gives the following example of waiting for a condition to be true on a test page after loading it:

```
this.remote
    .get(require.toUrl('./SomeTest.html'))
    .then(pollUntil('return window.ready;', 5000));
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't explain how to load the pollUntil helper in order to use it in the previous example... Does anybody have a complete working example that uses pollUntil ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

I think I found the answers: it works by loading module `intern/dojo/node!leadfoot/helpers/pollUntil`, as in:

```
define([
    'intern!object',
    'intern/chai!assert',
    'intern/dojo/node!leadfoot/helpers/pollUntil',
    '../Request',
    'require'
 ], function (registerSuite, assert, pollUntil, Request, require) {
```

Answer (score 1):

intern 4 uses

```
define([
  'dojo/request',
  'dojo/node!@theintern/leadfoot/helpers/pollUntil'
], 
function(request, _pollUntil) { 

   var pollUntil = _pollUntil.default;
   var registerSuite = intern.getInterface('object').registerSuite;
   var assert = intern.getPlugin('chai').assert;

});
```